# "rosmake teleop_base" gives "Failed to find stack for package [control_toolbox]"

Tags: ros, teleop-base, simulator-stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to get working the following simulation tutorial. I have electric on 10.04

http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot

When I perform the "rosmake teleop_base" I get the following flavor of error.

Failed to find stack for package [control_toolbox]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [control_toolbox]:Cannot locate installation of package control_toolbox: [rospack] couldn't find package [control_toolbox]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/swords/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/home/swords/ros_workspace/teleop_base]

Appreciate some help on this.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11565/%22rosmake-teleop_base%22-gives-%22failed-to-find-stack-for-package-%5Bcontrol_toolbox%5D%22/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question.
Simply remove reference to the control_toolbox dependency in the manifest.

---

Originally posted by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) with karma: 69 on 2011-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-18**:
The other option is to install the control_toolbox package. But if the dependency is unneeded it should be removed from the tutorial code.  If you could please file a ticket to get this fixed so it can be fixed for other future users.

**Comment by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on 2012-10-22**:
How do you know the dependence is not needed? However, if you want to install it you can find it there: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_controllers/tags/electric/control_toolbox/